# Using Node and mysql UPDATE "error: syntax error at or near "WHERE""

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to update my database. I have tried using the question marks and it will not work. It will work if I hard code values in.

This works

```
let sql = "UPDATE words SET guessedScrambled = true WHERE unkey=17"
 pool.query(sql, function(err, db_results){
```

This does not work

```
let sql = "UPDATE words SET guessedScrambled = ? WHERE unkey=?"
pool.query(sql, [true, 17], function(err, db_results){
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: I've tested both of your variations and they work. Perhaps the issue is specific to the version of MySQL you are running (I tested on 5.7.25) or the schema of your DB, table, or field. Can you provide an example of your table schema, as well as the full output of `console.log(err)` from your second query? Happy to help troubleshoot more.

Comment: Is this a simplified example of what your real code looks like? Does the value `true` come from the request body or request parameters? It's possible that you are passing in a string containing `"true"`